# Is there a way to copy/paste error or warning messages from Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4

Say I've got some compiler errors in Xcode. Say I want to ask about those errors on Stack Overflow.

How should I do that? Do I have to read the warning message and type?

So many people ask about the exact error with no misspelling; I bet there is a way to copy and paste those errors. What is it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you can how:

1) Cmd + 4. For Open a Issue Navigator

2) Click on "By Type" for sort by warning and error issues

3) Then finding your error, then Right click and Copy

4) Your error message in your clipboard and you can paste this at anywhere

Hope this help to you

Answer (score 4):

Press cmd+7 to get to the Log navigator, select the last build log, find your error message, right click and copy.